# Can't upload blob URL to Active Storage (ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blob, rails-activestorage

I would like to store data taken on the web in Active Storage in Rails. However, the data is not saved properly and I get an error in `video_tag`.

I have succeeded in creating the Blob data, but I have not been able to upload it.

**Error**

> ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature

```
<%= f.hidden_field :media, id: "download-video" %>

// => <input id="download-video" type="hidden" value="blob:http://localhost:3000/859031b4-022b-4e7e-be08-518c77e8e9d1" name="post[media]">
```

**app/models/post.rb**

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one_attached :media
end
```

**app/models/posts_controller.rb**

```rb
---
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.create(create_params)
  @post.save
end
---
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as I understand what you what to do you cannot do it like this.

Note that sending form with `input` value set to some URL will send string to the server but it is expecting file.

One solution would be downloading the file before creating `Post` in controller.

[Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53158776/activesupportmessageverifierinvalidsignature-error-when-updating-a-model-wit)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to find a way to download it.