# onDrop submit a form with a file (without using Ajax)

Tags: javascript, drag, drop

This could be a limitation of the environment but what I am trying to do is drop a file then have it post a file direct to the server PHP (no Ajax)... but the $_FILES variable is not correctly populated... Method: as the drop occurs the file object is taken and appended to a form which is submitted... This is normally done using and append to Ajax, but this creates an extra process that I don't want or need...

```js
function uploadFile(e) {

  file_obj = e.dataTransfer.files[0];

  uploadForm = document.getElementById("upload_form");

  // Add the input to the form
  uploadForm.append('file', file_obj);

  // Add the form to dom
  document.body.appendChild(uploadForm);

  // Just submit
  uploadForm.submit();


}
```

```html
<form action="upload.php" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="uploadFile(event)" ondragover="return false">
   <p>Drop file here</p>
   <input name="" type="submit">     
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried converting your file's data (text or binary) and converting it to a dataURL string and then using that dataURL to send to your form as a query argument? Might not work for large files.

Comment: I am fairly new to javascript how would i do this? lots of these form interaction things seem to be done asynchronously (waiting for an event) I think the root is timing or just things aren't hooked up to work this way?

Comment: You can try this, this is more straightforward then doing the text conversion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628011/how-to-upload-a-file-to-my-server-using-html

Answer (score -1):

You should try new FormData() in order to get files data.

Comment: Good advice, but could be better if you show how to do it with an example

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).