# PHP Drag & Drop File Upload with ExtJS

Tags: php, zend-framework, extjs

I have a widget I'm using that does a request to a method I created in a Zend controller. The user uploads an image to the server and the jpeg is POST'd to the server within the request body.

How do you access this on the PHP side? I've looked in $_POST, $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA (after setting the php.ini setting), $_FILES, and tried:

```
$data = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
```

All of those globals and variables are empty. I'm using charles proxy and you can see the request and the image binary data in it. I'll link a screenshot as soon as I can (imgur is down).

[image]

Edit: Screenshot

Edit: I'm getting somewhere:

```
public function filesAction() {

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $params  = $request->getParams();

        if ( $request->isPost() ) {

                    $httpContent = fopen( 'php://input', 'r' );
                    echo stream_get_contents( $httpContent );

        }
}
```

This is returning the binary data back to me in the response now, I just need to use fwrite() or something similar to create the image on the server and then I can move on to FTP'ing it where it needs to go.

Comment: Since you are using ZF, does `$this->getRequest()->getRawBody();` return the data from the image upload?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to create a single-file upload form using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198346/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-single-file-upload-form-using-php)

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Not a duplicate, this is sending Binary data through XHR and will not populate $_FILES, the data must be read from a stream and it's multi file upload through drag and drop.

Comment: @drew010 No, I looked at getRawBody() and so far it's empty as well. I've tried using php://input and read_stream_contents and that is also not working.