# Not able to save file on server

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, file, permissions

I have created a website where you can upload pictures and the pictures get saved on a server. I had a problem before where the information gets saved in the database but the file wont get saved on the server, I then changed the file rights to 777, which allowed me to upload files to the server. Now I tried uploading a file from another computer but I get the same problem as before. Information gets saved in the database but no file gets uploaded to the server. Anyone got any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Is your code pointing to the correct directory? + it's slightly impossible to know the exact fix for this problem, as there is no demonstrated code.

Comment: I don't quite get the *file rights* part of your question. Rights of what file you changed ? Have you set 777 on directory you save file to ?

Comment: Exactly I changed the rights to 777 on the directory where I save my files. The code is pointing at the correct directory since I don't get this problem on my own computer.

Comment: Weird. Maybe try to boost error_reportng. There may be be some helpful info. Anyway, why don't you store images in database (BLOB field) ?

Comment: @user3327442 if you have physical access to the Terminal, run the following; `ls -la /Path/ToDirectory`   It'll show you the current folders permission

Comment: Dont know if i wrote in the right place but it says: cannot access /Path/ToDirectory: No such file or directory

Comment: You must change /Path/ToDirectory to your own path where you have set that 777

Comment: what is the command for changing /Path/ToDirectory?

Comment: I mean instead of write /Path/ToDirectory use your own. For example: /bla/bla/bla/my/directory/with777

Comment: oh ok! I wrote again with my path and it displays all the files in the directory

Comment: it says "drwxrwxrwx" for the directory

Comment: Well, it is 777. If there is no plus sign, there is no ACL. Maybe try sudo touch file in this directory as wwwrun user ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check which is the error that returns when you try to upload the file.

Check on the Apache log (or the log of the web server that you use) to see what is causing the issue.

If you are not on a live enviroment (production) or a staging environment (uat), you could enable the error reporting by enabling on the runtime configuration (php.ini) or adding the following lines on your code:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Here is a [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198346/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-single-file-upload-form-using-php#answer-198459) to follow to implement a file upload.

Comment: Changing php.ini is excessive. Better describe how to prepare .htaccess

Comment: I believe it's better to identify the problem using the error message or the logs and then make adjustments. I don't think it's exaggerated to change the php.ini. If it's a local environment, it could be changed, unless that you are working on production or uat envs.

Comment: Its just about good practice. If someone will read your answer in the future, he will try to modify php.ini. He may not know he shouldn't do it on production env.