# undefined index $_FILES file upload

Tags: php, validation, undefined

I have this PHP function to validate files types and its extension uploaded in a form:

```
    public function acceptedFileTypes($valueofformfield, $fieldname) {     
        $allowed = array('doc', 'pdf', 'docx', 'jpg', 'gif','png');      
        $value = $_FILES[$valueofformfield]['name'];         //UNDEFINED VARIABLE
        $extension = end(explode(".", $value));

        $valid = !in_array($extension, $allowed); //STRICT STANDARDS: ONLY VARIABLES SHOULD BE PASSED BY REFERENCE 

        if ($valid  == FALSE) {
            $this->emailErrors[] = "Your uploaded files cannot be accepted; only .doc, .docx, .pdf, or .jpg files only in $fieldname";
        }
        return
```

var_dump($_FILES) reveals:

```
array (size=1)
  'fileAttach' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'mysql.init' (length=10)  //EXAMPLE FILE USED
      'type' => string 'application/octet-stream' (length=24)
      'tmp_name' => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\phpD106.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 101
```

If you noticed on the notes, there are errors that days i've have trying to find the answer. What is wrong with my php code. specifically:

1. What made '$value = $_FILES[$valueofformfield]['name'];' an undefined variable?
2. Is $extension = end(explode(".", $value)); a valid expression to get the extension of the uploaded file?
3. what made  $valid = !in_array($extension, $allowed); a wrong way of passing reference?

I`ve searched answers herein and in other site but to no avail.

help is much appreciated by this newbie. THANKS

Comment: Don't know what is causing your problem, but you could learn a few things on how to upload and code.. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198346/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-single-file-upload-form-using-php

Comment: And how are you calling the `acceptedFileTypes()` method?  Because in your example if you're not passing in "fileAttach" for `$valueofformfield`, then of course you'll see that error.

Comment: just a  silly question:  is correct: $value = $_FILES[$valueofformfield]['name']; or it must be: $value = $_FILES[$fieldname]['name']; ?

Comment: Crontab: Sorry im really a newbie, but what do you mean passing in fileattach. Thanks for reply

Comment: Dieter: Thanks for the tip, studying it right now

Answer (score 0):

$value = $_FILES[$valueofformfield]['name'];

My guess the value of valueofformfield is not 'fileAttach'....var_dump is your friend!

maybe it's : $value = $_FILES[$fieldname]['name']; -> //bit of a blind guess without your form.

if you get a undefined your warning your $value is not set so the param doens't exist. Which gives this error: ONLY VARIABLES SHOULD BE PASSED BY REFERENCE. Error is thrown here : $extension = end(explode(".", $value));

Check if params/keys exist (isset) to prevent errors!

$valid = !in_array($extension, $allowed); -> how save should your check be? Renaming a .exe file to docx will get it uploaded by using this check.

Comment: havent tried your suggestion $value = $_FILES[$fieldname]['name']. I used $fieldname as reference for the 'name='nameInFormField' in the HTML form; FYI. and i have used the same function format to validate other form fields and $fieldname just worked fine to them. Thanks

Comment: so why are you using $valueofformfield for your files if you are using $fieldname anywhere else.