# How to get an image from a user and store it in a folder on a raspberry pi using the html input tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, webserver

I am trying to use the input tag from Html to take an image from a user and store it on a web server that for now is my PC but in the future i want to transfer to it to my raspberry pi I don't want to use a SQL server for this project all that I need to know is preferably with HTML OR PHP Or JavaScript how could i take an image from a user and store it on a web server to be displayed later, also I am currently using xampp if that is of any use.

Comment: I don't actually understand, where would the script be stored ? if it's going to be stored on the raspberry pi well it's the same code, or are you trying to send the picture from your PC to the raspberry

Comment: I am trying to host the website of a raspberry pi so the script would hopefully be stored there and the user would input a picture and it would be stored on the raspberry pi where another script would access that image

Comment: Do you have external storage connected to RaspberryPi to handle images of substantial size?

Comment: I do have an external hard drive i don't expect a lot of users just for my friends and their friends  and thanks for the link to someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `change` event at `<input type="file">` element, `change` event, `FormData()`, `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest()`

```
<input type="file" accepts="image/*">
<script>
var input = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");
input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var file = this.files[0];
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append("file", file);
  fetch("/path/to/server", {method:"POST", body:data})
  .then(response => response.ok)
  .then(res => console.log(res))
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

look at this question: [What's the best way to create a single-file upload form using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198346/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-single-file-upload-form-using-php?noredirect=1&lq=1)

then you can write some bash script to automaticly copy files between your pc and RPi. Or you can mount disk from RPi in PC and store files from html form directly on it.